# I can not translate the theme created for WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I need to translate my wordpress theme.
I did:

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'text_domain', get_template_directory().'/language' );
```

in to function.php.
through the functions`__("string","text_domain")` and *poedit* I have generated files po and mo , but nothing translation.
what is the problem?
i have 
also tried with `_e() esc_html_e() esc_html__()` nothing.The problem is that I'm working in local?

Comment: Did you add the load_theme_textdomain within an action hook like 'after_setup_theme' or did you place it directly in the functions.php file?

Comment: I tried both of them but nothing. I preferred send directly

Comment: You should post more of your code so we can see what exactly is going on.

Comment: Maybe your path is wrong? Usually this folder is called languageS ?

Comment: no the directory It was created by me. (for mizaP) code for translate is end